# Resource can't be found even when it's present

Tags: asp.net, wpf, resources

I've got a really weird issue I can't fix within a Wpf Application. We built a Common Library containing many useful components, one of them is a fancy MessageBox which has the company style. There're three dictionaries that contains nearly everything we require:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Library;component/Style/Styles.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Library;component/Themes/Globals.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Library;component/Themes/Controls/Button/Template.xaml"/>
```

There's a footer for the MessageBox into Globals.xaml, footer uses a template from Template.xaml. It works perfectly but not in one case. I have a main window that dinamically create a plugin and open a window. This window is a regular Window Wpf application loaded through reflection. 
Method to open MessageBox is within the same DLL as Resource Dictionaries.

If I call this MessageBox method from the plugin it throws an exception because "Footer" is not found. I set a breakpoint before

```
window.ShowDialog();
```

And I see MergedDictionaries is empty into window. Also empty everywhere, only owner of this MessageBox contains those resources. Doing

```
window.FindResource("key");
```

Get a null value as expected. However, if I manually copy merged dictionaries using this code lines before open dialog:

```
foreach (var dict in owner.Resources.MergedDictionaries)
{
    window.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
}
```

And then look for window.FindResource("key") I can see the style, but even though it continues throwing an exception:

**Cannot find resource named '{Footer}'. Resource names are case sensitive.**

Footer style is used in this line of MessageBox:

```
<StatusBar Style="{StaticResource Footer}" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=window}"...
```

I've also tried to declare this resource into the DialogWindow in the library, even when I've not gonna be allowed to change it:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Library;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Library;component/Themes/Globals.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Library;component/Themes/Controls/Button/Template.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

I've been 2 days knocking my head on the monitor and nothing, everything I tried failed. Despite of breaking a monitor of course.
Ran out of ideas...

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the following things

- The resource dictionary Build Action is set to Page
- Every project that references the Style has a library reference to it (Even if you put the Dictionary in App.xaml if a project that doesn't reference the Resources Library then it wont find it
- Place the MergedDictionaries in App.xaml (or in the specific page you want to use them)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I did it. Weirdest thing of this I can debug the application and check with "FindResource" method wether or not that resource was loaded. Even if I force it it can't be found by the MessageBox.

Comment: sorry, not sure I understand.

what does this mean:
Every project that references the Style has a library reference to it (Even if you put the Dictionary in App.xaml if a project that doesn't reference the Resources Library then it wont find it.

How do I add a reference to a resource library? do you just mean under project options?